# What will be the query to get Student names for every individual study group?

Tags: sql, relational-database, plpgsql

**meetings** which looks like this:

| meeting_ID | place |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

**study_groups** which looks like this:

| study_group_id | meeting_id (fk) | topic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Basics |
| 2 | 2 | Photography |
| 3 | 1 | Film |

**students** which looks like this:

| student_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz |
| 2 | abc |
| 2 | pqr |

**group_members** which looks like this:

| study_group_id (fk) | student_id (fk) |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 10 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 11 |

A `meeting` has many `study_groups` and each `study_groups` has many `students`.

I want to find the student names in each group individually for `meeting_id = 1`.
Is that possible or not to do in the same query?

If not what should I do, please suggest me.

This is my present SQL query:

```
SELECT
    study_groups.study_group_id,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM group_members
     WHERE study_groups.study_group_id = group_members.study_group_id) AS no_of_students,
    study_groups.topic
FROM 
    study_groups
WHERE 
    study_groups.meeting_id = 1;
```

Now the table looks like:

| study_group_id | no_of_student | topic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Basics |
| 2 | 3 | Photography |

`student_name` column result in below is **demo** but I want the data as like this.

**The result I expect:**

| study_group_id | no_of_student | topic | `student_name` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Basics | `xyz, abc, pqr` |
| 2 | 3 | Photography | `abc, pqr` |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the students in the study group *and* you are using Postgres, you can aggregate them into an array:

```
SELECT sgs.study_group_id,
       (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(s.name)
        FROM group_members gm JOIN
             students s
             ON gm.student_id = s.student_id
        WHERE sg.study_group_id = gm.study_group_id
       ) AS student_names,
       sg.topic
FROM study_groups sg
WHERE sg.meeting_id = 1;
```